Constraints on literals in array initializations
Here is base code:
export const LETTERS = {
    // internal
    a: 'a',
    // external
    b: 'b',
    c: 'c',
} as const;

export const internalLetters = [
    LETTERS.a,
] as const;

export type LETTER_TYPE = typeof LETTERS[keyof typeof LETTERS];

Now assume I want to have a helper function which accept any letter and defines if it is internal:
const isInternal = (letter: LETTER_TYPE) => internalLetters.includes(letter);

And now the error appears:

Can you explain what is wrong with such code and how to achieve my goal?

Giving a type LETTER_TYPE to internalLetters array is not a solution, as it should contain the only letter: LETTERS.a

The typing of includes is a bit unintuitive with such a strictly typed array - the whole point of the method is to know whether or not a value is in there, but the compiler only allows arguments that definitely are. You either need to widen the array type (to e.g. readonly string[]) or narrow the letter type (to e.g. typeof internalLetters[number]) for the compiler to allow it.

You can cast internalLetters as ReadonlyArray<LETTER_TYPE> to be able to call includes on it.

@RickyMo, as I mentioned it's not a solution since any other 'not allowed' letter could be added to that array

You don't need to cast the internalLetters declaration, only cast it in the isInternal function right before calling includes. This won't affect the typing of internalLetters itself.

const isInternal = (letter: LETTER_TYPE) => (internalLetters as ReadonlyArray<LETTER_TYPE>).includes(letter);

@jonrsharpe but the compiler only allows arguments that definitely are: what basically makes no sense. Unfortunately both solutions won't work for me

@RickyMo okay, that's kind of a solution, thanks. Also I figured out that using .find or .findIndex instead of .includes also works for such cases

You only have to assert (not cast!) the type for that specific call, as other comments suggest. Whether the type itself should change is a separate discussion that's not for SO, see e.g. microsoft/TypeScript#53904.

@tykhan if TS know some variable value cannot take a particular type then it will point it out right. That is the whole point of type system. If you still try to assign a variable the value from that type, then you are not making use of TypeScript right.

If we check the type of internalLetters we get:
const internalLetters: readonly ["a"]

This means that it only allows "a" as its item value and nothing else. It doesn't even allow an empty array (see image below).

TypeScript enforces this constraint to such a level that calling internalLetters.includes first checks whether the supplied value can even be a member of internalLetters, i.e. it won't allow any superset of the allowed values; in your case it doesn't allow the value to be of type "a" | "b" | "c" when the only accepted value is "a".
There are a couple of ways to address this:

Use internalLetters.find to perform the isInternal check
Set internalLetters to be of explicit type readonly LETTER_TYPE[], allowing .includes to permit the general type LETTER_TYPE

You can find both of these approach in this TS Playground.

When narrowing a type with TypeScript's type predicate, you tell the compiler that you assume the given WiderType satisfies a type of the NarrowerType by casting the WiderType to the NarrowerType (as NarrowerType). This allows you to check if this statement is true using JavaScript. When combined with the is NarrowerType keyword, you tell the compiler to treat the given value as a NarrowerType when the function returns true.
In other words, for a set T, and set K being a subset of T, we check if a given member of T is also a member of K. Thus, a member of T is a type of K.
As you mentioned:

Giving a type LETTER_TYPE to internalLetters array is not a solution, as it should contain the only letter: LETTERS.a

This can be solved by combining as const with the satisfies keyword.
const LETTERS = {
    // internal
    a: 'a',
    // external
    b: 'b',
    c: 'c',
} as const;

type LETTER_TYPE = keyof typeof LETTERS

const internalLetters = [
    LETTERS.a,
] as const satisfies LETTER_TYPE[];

type INTERNAL_LETTER_TYPE = typeof internalLetters[number]

const isInternal = (letter: LETTER_TYPE): letter is INTERNAL_LETTER_TYPE => {
    return internalLetters.includes(letter as INTERNAL_LETTER_TYPE);
}

console.log(isInternal('a')) // true | 'a' is INTERNAL_LETTER_TYPE
console.log(isInternal('b')) // false | 'b' is LETTER_TYPE
console.log(isInternal('c')) // false | 'c' is LETTER_TYPE

